# ESCPOS GS C commands

Tags: escpos

Can you please explain to me what aL, aH, bL, bH stands for

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- aL = a low byte
- aH = a high byte
- bL = b low byte
- bH = b high byte

In this case a is the minimum serial number count value and b is the maximum serial number count value.